# Is there a Windows Explorer extension that shows an inline command prompt?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, mercurial

Does anybody know of a Windows Explorer extension that will add a pane giving an inline command prompt, set to the current directory?

I know that on Windows 7 I can Shift-Right Click and get Open Command Prompt here, but my desktop soon gets cluttered with windows when I do that.

The specific example that made me ask for this is my work with Mercurial: it would be great just to be able to go to my directory and type, in some pane in the window, "hg push", and see all my changes pushed up to the repository. But I can think of other uses as well, so I'm sure somebody must already have written this extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try typing into the address bar:

```
cmd /c notepad foo.txt
```

This opens up foo.txt in the current location of the Explorer window.  When whatever you execute finishes, or is closed, the CMD console closes.

I've noticed that I can run anything in my path by doing this - even batch scripts.  A pretty cool discovery I think!

I don't use Mercurial, so I cannot tell you if it would do what you want, but I think it will.

Comment: Opens two(!) new windows... I think that was something the OP wanted to AVOID!

Comment: @TFM: Just use the `/c` switch then.  This seems to be exactly what Sam wants  :D

Comment: Never knew you could do that. I think that's just what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add your own custom context menu entry. Look here: http://www.burgaud.com/open-command-window-here/

Change the command to "hg push" and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

If anything can do it, I bet [Nomad](http://www.nomad-net.info/) can. Looks like I'm going to have to install it if I want to find out definitively, though.

Comment: From a quick glance at the website, Nomad appears to be a replacement for Windows Explorer, rather than offering plug-ins